# Criar relacionamento bidirecional sem usar DTO?

Tags: jpa, spring, rest, relacionamento, entidade-relacionamento

Olá, estou num projeto e preciso fazer relacionamento bidirecional entre duas entidades, o relacionamento é `@OneToMany` `@ManyToOne`, até aí tudo bem. Mas gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de fazê-lo sem usar DTO?

```
@Entity
public class Answer extends BasicForum {

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    private Question question;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "answer")
    private List<CommentAnswer> commentList;
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Question extends BasicForum{

    private String title;
    private Integer views;

    @OneToMany(fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "question")
    private List<Answer> answerList;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "question")
    private List<CommentQuestion> commentList;
```

---

Agradeço a todos da comunidade.

Comment: O relacionamento já está bidirecional, teve algum problema?

Comment: @MatheusSilva o problema é o JsonIgnore, ele corta a bidirecionalidade pois ele ignora no json o atributo question dentro de answer, caso eu tire ele o relacionamento tende ao infinito e da um estouro de pilha pois uma question tem uma lista de answer, que cada atributo da lista tem uma question, que tem um lista de answer..... e assim vai tendendo ao infinito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente eu removi a lista de `Answer` de dentro de `Question`, e criei um método no `Controller` que me retorna as `Answers` a partir da `Question`.

*Answer:*

```
@Entity
public class Answer extends BasicForum {
    @ManyToOne
    private Question question;

    private Boolean bestAnswer;
    private Integer numberComments;

    //Outros metodos
}
```

---

*Controller:*

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/question/{id}")
public List<Answer> getAnswersByQuestion(@PathVariable("id") final String id) {
        return repository.findByQuestionIdAndDeadIsFalse(id);
}
```

---

*Repository:*

```
@Repository
public interface AnswerRepository extends SuperRepository<Answer> {
    List<Answer> findByQuestionIdAndDeadIsFalse(String questionId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para manipular serviços a estratégia comumente adota é usar DTOs, até para evitar esses problemas de entidades anotadas com dependências bidirecionais. Mesmo replicando informações é uma boa prática ter entidades DTO para representar uma entidade persistente que será manipulada por um serviço, pelo fato de separar o que é persistido do que é "transiente". Uma outra vantagem é inclusive "desnormalizar" algumas informações distribuídas em várias entidades, assim fica mais fácil manipular os dados pois você mantem num único ponto de acesso (no DTO) as informações requeridas/providas pelo serviço.